# Mongoose Schema.update doesn't update boolean

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have tried updating other fields and it works just fine.

The command I am using in my API:

```
  User.update({ email: targetUser.email }, { $set: { isAdmin: true }, $push: { 'log.updated': new Date() } }, function (err, user) {
  if (err) {
    responseObject.err = err;
    responseObject.data = null;
    responseObject.code = 422;

    return res.json(responseObject);
  }


  return res.json(responseObject);
});
```

To clarify, when I try to run this, the API returns a code 200, meaning everything worked fine, but when I check the database the isAdmin value wasn't changed.

Any suggestions would be helpful, running out of ideas here!

User Schema as requested:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, default: "", index: 'text' },
  email: { type: String, lowercase: true },
  role: { type: String, default: "" },
  meta: {
    skills: { type: Array, default: [], index: 'text' },
    about: { type: String, default: "", index: 'text' },
    education: { type: Array, default: [], index: 'text' },
    location: {
      address: {
        a: { type: String, default: "" },
        p: { type: String, default: "" },
        c: { type: String, default: "" }
      },
      geo: {
        lat: { type: Number, default: 0 },
        lng: { type: Number, default: 0 }
      }
    }
  },

  compMeta:
  {
    departments: { type: Array, default: [], index: 'text' },
    employees:
    [
      {
        emId: Number,
        empName: String,
        empDep: String  // Dunno if i should use Dep name or Dep ID gonna look in to that later
      }
    ],
  }
  ,
  settings: {
    search: {
      distance: {
        n: { type: Number, default: 100 },
        t: { type: String, default: "km" }
      }
    }
  },
  created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  //Rating is an array of objects that consist of rateing 0-100 , job database id , comments from the Company
  rating:
  [
    {
      rate: Number,
      jobId: Number,
      jobComments: String
    }
  ],
  /*rating:
  {
    userTotalRating: {type: Number, default: 0},
    ratingCounter : {type: Number, default: 0}
  }*/


  sensitive: {
    cpr_cvr: String,
  },
  stripe: { type: String },
  facebook: {},
  linkedin: {},
  log: {
    updated: { type: Array, default: [] }
  },
  hashedPassword: String,
  provider: { type: String, default: 'local' },
  salt: String
});
```

**UPDATE:**

Mongodb version: 3.0.7

Comment: What's the question/problem? It's not clear

Comment: I've added a small clarification, hope it helps :)

Comment: Can I see the schema model too?

Comment: @Michelem, I've updated the question with the schema!

Comment: I can't see `isAdmin` field

Comment: I had added it in the dist folder model ... stupid me, thanks, now it works!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out I just forgot to add the isAdmin field to my User Schema! Also, my call to the update was wrong, I changed it to this:

```
User.update({ email: targetUser.email }, { $set: { isAdmin: true }}, { $push: { 'log.updated': new Date() } }, function (err, user) {
  if (err) {
    responseObject.err = err;
    responseObject.data = null;
    responseObject.code = 422;

    return res.json(responseObject);
  }


  return res.json(responseObject);
});
```

Thanks to everyone that put an effort to help me! :)

Comment: Exactly the same here (:

Comment: same here, I also forgot to add the field on Schema. fixed now. !

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar problem. The solution was to add the callback.

This doesn't work:

```
Ride.updateOne({driver:req.body.id},{$set:{isBusy:true}});
```

This works:

```
Ride.updateOne({driver:req.body.id},{$set:{isBusy:true}},(e,s)=>{});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try updating two fields with $set

```
User.update({ email: targetUser.email }, { $set: { isAdmin: true, 'log.updated': new Date() } }, function (err, user) {
 if (err) {
responseObject.err = err;
responseObject.data = null;
responseObject.code = 422;

return res.json(responseObject);
 }
 return res.json(responseObject);
});
```

Hope it's works.

Comment: Hey Mariya, unfortunately I get the same result.

Comment: Tried that too, no change.

Comment: One last try.. updated the code. One more thing if it success then you will get true as response

Comment: Same thing, returns a 200 code and then nothing was changed in the DB.

Answer (score 0):

There is easier way to handle the issue. As per the documentation, the second parameter is the object where you can update the statement.

```
A.findByIdAndUpdate(id, update, options, callback)
```

So you just need to take everything inside the update object.

```
User.update({ email: targetUser.email, $set: {isAdmin: true}} // ... etc
```