# Update boolean with Mongoose

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

I have created an app where i can create a to do list. And i have a status that is false when created. The status i supposed to represent if the object done or not.

My mongoose schema look like this in **server.js**:

```
// Create mongoose schema
var issueSchema = mongoose.Schema ({
    issue: String,
    date: String,  
    status: Boolean,    
 });    

 // Create mongoose model
Issue = mongoose.model('Issue', issueSchema);
```

When i press my button in on my index.html im using angular to send the id trough to the server.js file.

```
// API PUT ========================
app.put('/issueList/:id', function(req, res){
var id = req.params.id;

Issue.findById(id, function(err, Issue) {
    console.log("Object with ID: " + id); // Correct ID

   // I need code here

 });
});
```

I need help updating the boolean value to true if false or false if true. Or should i skip the boolean value and use something else?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mongoose Schema.update doesn't update boolean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33997078/mongoose-schema-update-doesnt-update-boolean)

Comment: If i use that i can change from False to True(if false is default), but not  the other way around

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the issue by id and then save it back to MongoDB after making the changes in success callback.

```
Issue.findById(id, function(err, issue) {
    issue.status = !issue.status;
    issue.save(function (err) {
        if(err) {
        console.error('ERROR!');
      }
  });
});
```

I am not sure about the possibility of toggling boolean field atomically as of now in MongoDB.

Comment: It worked! Thank you! But can ju explain this one for me   ` issue.status = !issue.status;` ???

Comment: @mackeemackee  When we do **findById**, It returns the matching document. We can manipulate the document according to our requirement on the server like we are toggling the **status** field in this case. When we are doing  `issue.status = !issue.status;`, it just works as normal javascript statement, evaluating value at right side and assigning to left side. When we call save, it actually replaces the modified object with the existing one in the database.  We should take care of **race Conditions** while doing complex modifications using this way of an update.

Comment: Why don't we use `findByIdAndUpdate` instead of `findById`?

Answer (score 1):

First, i dont think you should use same variable name outside and inside the function. In this case `Issue` is same, change it to `issue`.

And you can try this to update.

```
Issue.findById(id, function(err, issue) {
    console.log("Object with ID: " + id); // Correct ID
    issue.status = !issue.status;
    issue.save(function(err,result){...});
 });
});
```